# TimeZone Issue during DayLight Saving

Tags: unix, timezone

I just been bugged by the Day light saving hours

I seem that `3rd November 2013 01:00:00` start EST time

Now ever Time I set my time to 3rd November 2013 00:58:xx(some seconds)

and run `date`

it give me valid Time zone i.e `EDT`

but

even after the time pass 01:00:00 and I still query the date library

I still see the Time zone as `EDT` and not `EST`

have a look at this screenshot [image]

You can clearly see the Time zone saying as EDT even when it is EST

any one has a clue for this

### Update

There is one other finding I found if I restart my machine I see this

[image]

### More Update

Before Restart 
   [image]

After Restart 
   [image]

Comment: Just a note: copy/pasting text from the console would have been enough. Why the screenshots?

Comment: To prove the downvoter that whatever I saying is correct

Answer (score 2):

What was the current time and timezone when you set the clock ?

In any case, use `date -u` to figure out what exactly the system clock is set to.

EST time doesn't start at 01:00 but at 02:00 which turns to 01:00 EST.

Comment: see the Update now even I miffed with the fact that if the EST is suppose to start at 2:00 why is it showing EST for time that follow in 01:xx window

Comment: Both 1:00 EST and 1:00 EDT do exist.

Comment: Sorry didn't get what you meant in last comment

Comment: I mean there are different two period of time from 1am to 2am, one of each being EST so you can't write EST starts at 2:00 without specifying which 2:00.

Comment: `s/different two/two different/`